# How to display only a portion of graph using PYG and networkx

Tags: graph, networkx, pytorch-geometric

Is there way to visualize only a portion of a large graph (e.g. 30k nodes).
I tried to visualize a graph with 10k nodes using networkx. But it doesn't give a meaningful image due to a large no of overlapping nodes in the image.

```
g = torch_geometric.utils.to_networkx(data, to_undirected=True)
nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use nx.draw(g.subgraph([specifed_nodes]), with_labels=True) and then add plt.show() you should be able to get only part of the graph [networkx documentation - Drawing](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html#drawing)
. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much VenjixFirewire. It worked.